# Make JSON array Flot compatible

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, flot

I have some PHP code that outputs a JSON array when $.getJSON is called:

```
.
.
.
$data = array_combine($date_dispatched,$amount);

echo json_encode($data);
```

This is collected by:

```
$.getJSON('statistics_get.php',function(output) {
            $.plot($("#graph_1"), [{
                        data: output,
                        lines: {show:true}
                        }]
                    );
});
```

Now, using firebug, the response I get back is of the form:

```
{"0":"0","1296658458000":"566","1296725534000":"789","1297072385000":"890","1297072388000":"435"}
```

Flot is not processing this data. I believe [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) needs it to be in the form [[1,2],[4,5],[6,9]] etc. So my question is, what is the best way of getting this JSON array into the correct form for flot to read and produce a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `array_combine`, since it doesn't do what you need. Doing "zip" in PHP is a little bit unpleasant, but you should be able to manage with:

```
function make_pair($date, $amount) {
    return array($date, $amount);
}

$data = array_map('make_pair', $date_dispatched, $amount);
```

And then JSON-encode that.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at example two here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
you will see that you can have json_encode return an array instead of an associative object
Would that not be the solution rather than

```
var flotArr = []
var cnt=0;
for (var o in data) flotArr[cnt++]=[o,data[o]]
```

Comment: I'm with you when you say use json_encode on a non-associative array (thanks for pointing that out) however I'm not sure how I would then combine both sets of data into the correct form. How does the code you have supplied achieve this?

Comment: the code I gave took the object you have NOW and creates `[[0,0],[1296658458000,566],[1296725534000,789],[1297072385000,890],[1297072388000,435]]` which is what you said you wanted